# Search refinement "No values found" Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, refinement-panel, refiner

I have multiple custom fields that I have mapped to the RefineableString fields. All of them are set to a "Multi-value Refinement Item". In the Sample Values I get "No values found".

Refinement is working for OOTB items like Author and Created. 
[image]

This image is how the document one of the values is defined:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could be just a matter of Office 365 needing to reindex the content to correclty setup the new mappings for your managed properties. How long ago did you do the mapping?

Comment: I mapped it yesterday. I also manually re indexed everything after I first ran into the problem.

Comment: IIRC, things like this need a full crawl to complete, and we don't know when full crawls are executed on the tenants

Comment: That's odd, because I have had the content in there for a few days now

Comment: Try editing a few values to trip a crawl.

Comment: That worked, It also helped that I updated the refineable string values on the admin side rather site side

Answer (score 0):

I have already provided a detailed answer for the same question. Pls refer below [Reference Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/147500/managed-properties-not-available-as-refiners-on-content-search-web-part-sharepo/150308#150308)

Any changes to the search controls such as refinement panels or managed properties needs a full crawl either to the entire site or the specific lists/libraries in which the fields were created. also, many time i noticed the preview is not working but it will fetch the results once publishing on the search page.