# Managed Properties not available as Refiners on Content Search web part (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, content-search-web-part, refiner

I have managed metadata site columns where I’ve mapped the ows_ crawled property from a library to ‘RefinableString’s in the search schema. The ‘refinable’ box is ticked and I did this a few days ago now. I’m on SharePoint Online so can’t control the search crawls.

These refinable strings can be selected using a search refinement web part and they’re bringing back the relevant values. I just can’t see them to use on the refinement tab on a content search web part. I don't have any other refiners or query terms which would stop results with these properties being returned. Is there something I should check or something that controls their availability on this tab.

Thanks

Comment: How long ago did you set those up, I believe it takes a full crawl to be visible, and if you just set them up, it might be a day or more until they are available.

Comment: About 3 days ago now. I would have though a full crawl would have ran by now.

Comment: So, I have the refiners up and going, but whenever I try to search something in the search box either by name or title or metadata, it will always return 0 items, do you know why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint online, **RefinableStrings** are the only elements to map the crawled properties to the custom managed properties if you need those to be as refinable and different datatype other than text and Boolean.But once the mapping is done, you need to re-index either the specific library/lists or the entire site before the results show-up in the refinement panels. In most cases,  what i observed was even the refinement panel preview was also not working but once you save the search page the results will soon come on the pages as expected. Also, I would say the indexing time depends on the amount of content for crawling and it certainly doesn't need days of time.

I would also recommend to go through the documentation provided by Microsoft specific to SharePoint online. [Reference link on indexing in SharePoint online](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Manually-request-crawling-and-re-indexing-of-a-site-a-library-or-a-list-9afa977d-39de-4321-b4ca-8c7c7e6d264e?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA)

Overall information can be found in : [reference-2](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Manage-the-search-schema-in-SharePoint-Online-d4fab46d-ba41-4c03-9d4c-32b5b33198b6#__toc351360846)

Comment: So, I have the refiners up and going, but whenever I try to search something in the search box either by name, title or metadata, it will always return 0 items, do you know why this might be?

Comment: have you first tested in the search configuration (refiners configuration page) before trying in the actual search page. if everything looks good, then it should be working there itself

Comment: When I try in one library, the small search brings me info through the metadata fields, title or name. I made a page with a Search box, refiners and results, as long as I use the refiners I get results but when I try using the search box it brings nothing.

Comment: its strange, In SharePoint Online we really cant control the time and content sources that the crawler works on. I would suggest to leave it for 15 min then try to do a search or infact try doing  a manual indexing on the specific libraries to force the crawler to kick start.

Comment: Please look at this, the filters are working, not the search itself https://preview.ibb.co/b1gmO6/image.png